# Cannot execute binary from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a bunch of commands I need to run as I ssh into my cloud desktop. I thought about making a script which would execute those for me. The script however shows the error `cannot execute binary file`. The commands work fine if run independently directly on the console, but from the script they are erroring out.

Sample script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if cmd1 -f; then
    cmd2 -o
else
  echo "Failed to authenticate."
  exit 1
fi
```

When I run the above I get `./daily.sh: line 3: /usr/local/bin/cmd2: cannot execute binary file`.

I don't think this a architecture problem(32bit vs 64bit) because `cmd2` runs without any problem directly(outside the script).

**Some helpful outputs**

- **uname -a**: `Linux dummyHostName 4.9.217-0.1.ac.205.84.332.metal1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 2 15:19:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- **ldd /usr/local/bin/cmd2**: `not a dynamic executable`
- **file /usr/local/bin/cmd2**: `/usr/local/bin/cmd2: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable`
- **ls -l /usr/local/bin/cmd2**: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 owner1 owner2 659976 Mar 15  2018 /usr/local/bin/cmd2`

Difference between the file generated by `set > cmd-line.env` and `set > script.env`. You can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L0UOuJe5FDq_0ZFhucwY54vU2eMG4kh6/view?usp=sharing)

PS. I can't run by using `sudo` for running the script, since the `cmd1` infers my username and with `sudo` that goes for a toss and the command fails.

Edit: Added file with difference from command `set > cmd-line.env` and `set > script.env`

Comment: not clear if you're relying on $PATH to add `/usr/local/bin` to `cmd2`. I would bet when you run `cmd2` from the cmd-line, the $PATH is finding a different version. try `type cmd2` or `which cmd2` from cmd-line. Also the "errors" you get from `ldd` and `file` make me think you have installed a MacOS binary on a non Mac system? Good luck.

Comment: `which cmd2` returns `/usr/local/bin/cmd2`. The command's path is updated in the $PATH variable. I've tried putting the complete path in the script as well. Same error.

The OS is a custom OS vended from my organization. The cloud desktop are pre-laoded with this.

Comment: It really has to be differences between your script's environ and the cmd-line. 1) `set > cmd-line.env` and then 2) tmp add `set > script.env` to your script then 3) `diff *.env` ? WIthout being there, that's all I got. Good luck.

Comment: Added the diff file. Doesn't look like anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Don't show the diff file. Show some [MRE], that is your *real* shell script. I suspect your shell is `zsh`

Comment: Also give in your question the `~/.zshenv` and `~/.zshrc` on your Linux computer.

Answer (score 1):

> `file /usr/local/bin/cmd2` : /usr/local/bin/cmd2: *Mach-O* 64-bit x86_64 executable

It is likely that `/usr/local/bin/cmd2` is an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) for MacOSX for Apple computers. Perhaps your particular Linux computer has some settings (thru [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) ...) to run them in an emulator.

[Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) and [MacOSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) are different [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), even if both run on x86-64 and both are Unix like. Read a good [textbook about operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). On most Linux systems, binary executable files started by [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (by your [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)) are in the [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) format.

If you have legal access to the source code for `cmd2`, consider recompiling and rebuilding it on your Linux system. Otherwise, ask the supplier of your executable binary for a file suitable for your particular linux distribution (perhaps some [package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager)), and check with [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) that all shared librarius dependencies are available. Use also [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (perhaps on your shell) to understand what is going on. Consider also replacing `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash -vx`  to get a trace of what the shell does. Or with  `#!/bin/zsh -vx` if you prefer [zsh](https://zsh.org/).

Ber also sure that your [`$PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) is what should be expected for [execvp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) or for your interactive shell. Use also the `which` command.

**Without more details about your `$SHELL` and its configuration** (e.g. your files `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshenv`, `~/.zshrc`) **we cannot help you more**.

Comment: I don't have access to source code of `cmd2` since it is a binary from my organization. If this binary was a MacOSX binary how come it works when I run it from terminal directly but only fails when running from a script? My initial thought was the same as yours but then, since the command is running fine from terminal directly I thought I was wrong.

Comment: @Belphegor21: In theory, the difference could be because the **loading** of the program when running from the script, is obviously performed by `sh`, and interactively, you are running a different shell. I had expected that this should not matter, because in both cases, they both should just use the `exec` system call, but (assuming you are using bash interactively), try a `sh -c cmd2` and a  `bash -c cmd2`. Do both show the error message you get from the script?

Comment: @user1934428 You are right! `sh -c cmd2` and `bash -c cmd2` shows the error as on script but `zsh -c cmd2` runs the command. I'm using zsh shell. I changed the `#!bin/sh` to `#!bin/zsh` and it worked. Post your answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @Belphegor21 : I'm a bit reluctant to post this already as an answer yet, because I don't think that the shell alone is responsible for it, and a good answer should be helpful for the general case. Hence, we would have to find out, **why** zsh is doing it differently here. Did you verify at least, that `zsh -f -c cmd2` also does not show an error, so that we can make sure that it is **only** the shell that matters?

Comment: We cannot answer. You could. I don't know what are your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zshenv`  settings (or your `~/.profile`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Just for clarification: If I have an _interactive_ zsh, and from this, I invoke a shell script which has `#!/bin/zsh`, but not `#!/bin/zsh -i`, is the shell running this script also assumed to be interactive? I would say it is not, and if it is not interactive, I would conclude that the content of `.zshrc` does not influence the outcome of the cmd `zsh -c cmd2`, as the OP explained in his most recent comment.

Comment: @user1934428: This is explained in documentation of [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and of [zsh](http://zsh.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Could you maybe point out in detail, which part of the pages you linked, would explain not only the observations which the OP expressed in his question, but also in his comments? To be honest, I don't see it.

Comment: @user1934428: to your previous comment `zsh -f -c cmd2` is able to run the command without an issue.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I use `oh-my-zsh` and my zshrc is the default created  by it with the addition of a few aliases and some zsh plugins.

Comment: @Belphegor21: Just to make sure that in all cases the **same**  cmd2 is being run: Do `bash -c "type cmd2"` and `zsh -c "type cmd2"` output the same path?

Comment: @user1934428 exact same output of both the command. I also tried `sh -c "type cmd2"`, same for that as well.

Comment: @Belphegor21 : I don't know what kind of magic zsh has builtin here then, since we can exclude your zsh-files from responsibility for the effect. You can either just be happy about it, or you can ask again (using the `zsh` tag) on SO, why zsh can do here what bash does not.